# OpenAPI SpringBoot 3, how to add global error response codes

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am trying to configure Swagger in Spring Boot 3 project, and I want to set HTTP status codes responses globally instead of copy pasting code on top of each end point. I remember we used to do it in Swagger 2 or something with `Docket`, but now things are converted to OpenAPI and I am failed to find a way to do so.

Can some one please help me modifying following code so that I add responses globally.

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI usersMicroserviceOpenAPI() {

        Server localServer = new Server()
                .url("http://localhost:8080")
                .description("A Server URL");

        Contact contact = new Contact()
                .email("hi@example.com")
                .name("Exampl man");

        Info info = new Info()
                .contact(contact)
                .description("Spring Boot 3 + Open API 3")
                .summary("Demo of Spring Boot 3 & Open API 3 Integration")
                .title("Sample")
                .version("V1.0.0")
                .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").url("http://springdoc.org"));

        return new OpenAPI().info(info).
                addServersItem(localServer);
    }
}
```

I donot want to write following on top of each API

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad Request",
                    content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorRes.class))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Resource Not Found",
                    content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                            schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorRes.class))})
    })
```

I tried creating an interface which have above annotation and implemented on every REST Controller, it does the magic, but it removes the default 200 response and returned Class object as per the signature of method.

Comment: OAS does not have a global responses definition. Each endpoint needs to be defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the method creating an `OpenApiCustomizer` bean to the `OpenApiConfig` class as shown below.

```java
  @Bean
  public OpenApiCustomizer openApiCustomizer() {
    ResolvedSchema errResSchema =
        ModelConverters.getInstance().resolveAsResolvedSchema(new AnnotatedType(ErrorRes.class));
    Content content =
        new Content().addMediaType("application/json", new MediaType().schema(errResSchema.schema));
    return openApi ->
        openApi
            .getPaths()
            .values()
            .forEach(
                pathItem ->
                    pathItem
                        .readOperations()
                        .forEach(
                            operation ->
                                operation
                                    .getResponses()
                                    .addApiResponse(
                                        "400",
                                        new ApiResponse()
                                            .description("Bad Request")
                                            .content(content))
                                    .addApiResponse(
                                        "404",
                                        new ApiResponse()
                                            .description("Resource Not Found")
                                            .content(content))));
  }
```

It will append the API responses to all paths in your application.

Comment: that is amazing, how did you manage to find out this, where everyone is saying its impossible in newer version?? Please do shed some light on it, what was the thought process?

Comment: I discovered that `OpenApiCustomizer` can be used to customize the `OpenApi` object in [the documentation](https://springdoc.org/#how-can-i-customise-the-openapi-object). Then, I followed the same logic as for constructing the `@ApiResponse` annotation. The tricky part was defining the content, which I managed to solve using the trial and error method.